# Moving data from all columns to column A

Tags: vba, excel

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfbsE.png)

I have data in the format as shown in the linked image. How can I go through each row and move the data to Column A? In the end, all data will appear only in Column A in the same order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I am trying nested for loops to start at a row, go through columns, identify which is the first non-blank empty column, copy the contents of that column and paste them to the first column for that row. Then do the same for next row. I have figured out how to loop, but the bigger issue are the "fake" empty cells (copying data from a webpage), which can't be cleared using .ContentClear. Doing research to figure that out now. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you post your code, it can be helpful